# Python APNs background connection

Tags: python, google-app-engine

What would be the best practice in this scenario?

I have an App Engine Python app, with multiple cron jobs. Instantiated by user requests and cron jobs, push notifications might be sent. This could easily scale up to a total of +- 100 pushes per minute.

Setting up and tearing down a connection to APNs for every batch is not what I want. Neither is Apple advising to do this. So I would like to keep the connection alive, even when user requests finish or when a cron finishes. Possibly with a timeout (2 minutes no pushes, then close then connection).

Reading the GAE documentation, I couldn't figure out if there even is such a thing available. Also, I might need this to be available in different apps and/or modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the messages in a pull taskqueue and have a backend instance (or a cron job) to process the tasks

Comment: So where do I keep a reference to the alive connection?

Answer (score 0):

First, please take a look at [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/). It's cool and you can use it easier than APNS's protocol.

If you can not use GCM (because of code refactoring, etc ...), I think [AppEngine Managed VM](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/) is suitable for your situation now. Managed VM is something that stands between AppEngine and Compute Engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the datastore (eventually shadowed by memcache for performance) to persist all the necessary APN (or any other) connection/protocol status/context info such that multiple related requests can share the same connection as if your app would be a long-living one.

Maybe not trivial, but definitely feasible.

Some requests may need to be postponed temporarily, depending on the shared connection status/context, that's true.